# Printing pixels on webpage in "real" units

Tags: browser, svg, printing, pixel

I made an SVG rectangle in a browser. I would like to be able to print it in inches based on user input (I have width and height input fields). So far, I have been able to scale it appropriately in the browser - it shows up on my screen properly sized based on whatever input I put in - 2"x3", 5"x8", etc. BUT when printed, it's never the same. The printed version is always different, smaller. I'm making a template, so I'd like to be able to build something in the browser and print it in "real" units - say, inches, for this example.

What's happening and how can print what I see on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Pixels are not real-world units, so you won't be able to *consistently* do what you want across devices(screens,printers etc).

The formula for converting a pixel to a mm is:

```
mm = (pixels * 25.4) / DPI
```

**D.P.I** = *Dots Per Inch* of the device you are viewing this on.

Your screen is most likely 96 DPI while your printer is more than that, thus making the object appear smaller.

You can hack your way around this by scaling appropriately just before printing, IF you are certain of the DPI of the device in question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found a website that does something similar to what I am looking for...http://www.templatemaker.nl/ - user input goes in and a printable image comes out. How is it working here?

Comment: it creates a PDF for printing that *might* have some notation for real unit measurements, but I'm not too sure about that. However I doubt that the sizing on the screen corresponds to *real size* across screens.